# DateTimePicker different parameters on different fields

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I use 'DateTimePicker' (http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) on my date fields.

I would to manage different options on my date fields.

By instance:

- field "Birthdate" : allowBlank = false, format = 'Y-m-d'
- field "appointmentdate" : allowBlank = true, format = 'd-m-Y'

my javascript is

```
jQuery(document).on('ready page:change', function() {

    var datefield = jQuery("[data-behaviour~='my-datepicker']");
    datefield.datetimepicker({
        format: datefield.attr('data-dateformat') || 'Y-m-d',
        timepicker:false,
        allowBlank: datefield.attr('data-allowblank'),
        lang: datefield.attr('data-lang') || 'en'
    });

});
```

My problem is all 'options' (allowblank, format) are sames for all dates fields !

I can't make my datetimepicker function apply only on the field which has the option (allowblank=true only for 'appointmentdate'...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready page:change', function() {

    var datefields = jQuery("[data-behaviour~='my-datepicker']");

    datefields.each(function(){
        $(this).datetimepicker({
            format: $(this).attr('data-dateformat') || ($(this).attr('data-allowblank') ? 'd-m-Y' : 'Y-m-d'),
            timepicker:false,
            allowBlank: $(this).attr('data-allowblank'),
            lang: $(this).attr('data-lang') || 'en'
        });
    });

});
```

Or simply specify it in the `data-dateformat` attribute in the HTML code.

Comment: Thank's T.S.May be I wasn't clear : I try to "pass" parameters to my *two* date fields, but *differents* parameters (I don't want same behaviour of this fields). Plus, in your answer, you mix 'data-dateformat' parameter with 'data-allowblank' parameter. Thank's

Comment: As far as I understand it, you want the `format`-parameter to be different based on the `data-allowblank` attribute, right? That's what's happening here.
`format: datefield.attr('data-dateformat') || ...` means: if `data-dateformat` is set, use that, otherwise, use `...`
And, `(datefield.attr('data-allowblank') ? 'd-m-Y' : 'Y-m-d')` means: if `data-allowblank` is true, then use 'd-m-Y', otherwise, use 'Y-m-d'.
Which is what you ask for right?

Comment: No. I want : Field1 with behaviour "allow blank" and "format US" and Field1 with behaviour "doesn't allow blank" and "format FR". But currently, I have the same beahaviour for these 2 fields ("allow blank" and "format US"). As though the function is apply on all elements `[data-behaviour~='my-datepicker']` and not object by object, separatly. Thank's T.S.

Comment: You're right, I updated my answer, now it loops through each individual object.

Comment: It's ok ! Thank you very much T.S. :-)